# How to add second subchild in XML using VBA

Tags: xml, vba, vbscript

Hi am trying to add second child to xml, But unable to do it please help me.

Example:

```
<parent1>
<child>
    <child2> childname </child2> 
</child> 
</parent1>
```

Mycode

```
            Set objxmlPayloadHeader = xmlDoc.createElement("Parent1")
            objQueryHeader.appendChild objxmlPayloadHeader
            Set objxmlPayloadChildHeader = xmlDoc.createElement("Child")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build the XML as you have it above, add these lines of code to the end of your code:

```
    objxmlPayloadHeader.appendChild objxmlPayloadChildHeader
    Set objxmlPayloadChild2Header = xmlDoc.createElement("Child2")
    objxmlPayloadChild2Header.Text = "childname"
    objxmlPayloadChildHeader.appendChild objxmlPayloadChild2Header
```